# Has my history of body building made me permanently stronger? (Despite quitting years ago)

Tags: muscle, strength-training, body-building

From the age of 16-19, I went to the gym 6 days a week, ate and slept well and was in **excellent** physical fitness.

Now I am 24, haven't worked out in 5 years, and have a terrible sleeping pattern (4-7 hours a night), and eat even worse! My body is gone well and truly to seed, but despite all this, I am a lot stronger physically than all of my friends, even those who exercise regularly.

Why is this?

Comment: Consider how you spent your prime muscle building years vs. how they did.

Comment: There might be a lot of conditions involved, e.g. genetics. I think it's a at least quite widely held notion that muscles built from the gym only keep up as long as one keeps regularly exercising.

Answer (score 1):

Studies do suggest the existence of "muscle memory", possibly related to the nuclei of muscle cells (myonuclei). See [here](http://jeb.biologists.org/content/219/2/235#sec-3) for instance. Still, the precise dynamics and hysteresis of strength and their causes do not seem to be fully explored yet.